# How to iterate over boost graph to get incoming and outgoing edges of vertex?

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, boost, c++17

I am trying to iterate over boost graph. While iterating, I am trying to find incoming edges and outgoing edges from that vertex.  But I am getting segmentaion fault.
I tried to debug and found the line where it throws segmentation fault.

(vertex -> vertex of the graph of which incoming and outgoing edges needs to find out)
(graph -> boost graph )

```
//Finding out edges of vertex
    boost::graph_traits<BGType>::out_edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
    boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges( vertex, graph ); // error at this line
    for( boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges(vertex, graph); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
    {
        auto target = boost::target ( *ei, graph );
        graph[target]._isVisible = false;
    }

    //Finding in edges of vertex
    boost::graph_traits<BGType>::in_edge_iterator ein, ein_end;
    boost::tie(ein, ein_end) = in_edges( vertex, graph ); // error at this line
    for( boost::tie(ein, ein_end) = in_edges(vertex, graph); ein != ein_end; ++ein)
    {
        auto source = boost::source ( *ein, graph ); 
        graph[source]._isVisible = false;
    }
```

Comment: The error is most likely in BGType, vertex or graph. Take example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/graph/example/print-out-edges.cpp make it to work and then compare what you did wrongly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges( vertex, graph ); // error at this line
boost::tie(ein, ein_end) = in_edges( vertex, graph ); // error at this line
```

Both comments suggest that either `graph` or `vertex` are invalid. Check that `graph` is still a valid reference to an object.

If so, then "obviously" `vertex` is incorrect. It could be out-of-range. Consider checking it:

```
void hide_neighbours(BGV vertex, BGType& graph) {
    assert(vertex < num_vertices(graph));
```

And while you're at it, we can simplify the implementation:

```
void hide_neighbours(BGV vertex, BGType& graph) {
    assert(vertex < num_vertices(graph));
    using boost::make_iterator_range;

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(vertex, graph)))
        graph[target(e, graph)]._isVisible = false;
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(vertex, graph)))
        graph[source(e, graph)]._isVisible = false;
}
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/bcT4W3Pjs)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>

struct VertexProps {
    bool _isVisible = true;
};

using BGType = boost::adjacency_list< //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::bidirectionalS,            //
    VertexProps>;
using BGV = BGType::vertex_descriptor;

void hide_neighbours(BGV vertex, BGType& graph) {
    assert(vertex < num_vertices(graph));
    using boost::make_iterator_range;

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(vertex, graph)))
        graph[target(e, graph)]._isVisible = false;
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(vertex, graph)))
        graph[source(e, graph)]._isVisible = false;
}

int main() {
    BGType graph(8);
    add_edge(1, 5, graph);
    add_edge(5, 3, graph);
    add_edge(3, 7, graph);
    add_edge(7, 4, graph);

    add_edge(6, 5, graph);
    add_edge(2, 5, graph);

    auto annotate = boost::make_function_property_map<BGV>([&graph](auto v) {
        auto id = std::to_string(v);
        return graph[v]._isVisible ? id : "(" + id + ")";
    });

    print_graph(graph, annotate, std::cout << std::boolalpha);

    hide_neighbours(4, graph);
    print_graph(graph, annotate, std::cout << "\nNeigbours of 4 hidden:\n");

    hide_neighbours(5, graph);
    print_graph(graph, annotate, std::cout << "\nNeigbours of 5 hidden:\n");
}
```

Prints

```
0 --> 
1 --> 5 
2 --> 5 
3 --> 7 
4 --> 
5 --> 3 
6 --> 5 
7 --> 4 

Neigbours of 4 hidden:
0 --> 
1 --> 5 
2 --> 5 
3 --> (7) 
4 --> 
5 --> 3 
6 --> 5 
(7) --> 4 

Neigbours of 5 hidden:
0 --> 
(1) --> 5 
(2) --> 5 
(3) --> (7) 
4 --> 
5 --> (3) 
(6) --> 5 
(7) --> 4
```

Note that if you specify an invalid vertex you'll get:

```
sotest: /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:17: void hide_neighbours(BGV, BGType&): Assertion `vertex < num_vertices(graph)' failed.
```

### OTHER HINTS

If the above doesn't immediately remove/expose the issue then you have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Perhaps `graph` is indeed a dangling reference, or `graph` has been modified in illegal ways (e.g. removing vertices that weren't cleared).

Feel free to post another question with more relevant code if you need help finding such causes.

Comment: Can you look into this question ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996393/how-to-iterate-over-boost-graph-and-hide-not-connected-vertex