# How to iterate over boost graph and find neighbor's neighbor also?

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, boost, c++17

The following figure shows bi-directional graph. I have represented following graph using `boost-graph`.
[image]

I have iterated from `v1` --> `v2`  and `v1` --> `v3` but I am not able to visit from `v3` --> `v4`.  How to do that ?

Here is my code:
(vertex = V1) and
(graph = boost graph )

```
 //Finding out edges of vertex
    boost::graph_traits<BGType>::out_edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
    boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges( vertex, graph ); 
    for( boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges(vertex, graph); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
    {
        auto target = boost::target ( *ei, graph );
        graph[target]._isVisible = false;
    }

    //Finding in edges of vertex
    boost::graph_traits<BGType>::in_edge_iterator ein, ein_end;
    boost::tie(ein, ein_end) = in_edges( vertex, graph ); 
    for( boost::tie(ein, ein_end) = in_edges(vertex, graph); ein != ein_end; ++ein)
    {
        auto source = boost::source ( *ein, graph ); 
        graph[source]._isVisible = false;
    }
```

Comment: "every edge is also considered as vertex" citation needed?

Comment: @MarcGlisse  If it is confusing, then I am removing that statement.  Because that is not going to affect. I have traversed, from `v1` to `v3` and before going to visit `v2`, I want to fully iterate over `v3` means, I want to visit `v4` and then I will visit `v2`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse  I can traverse from `v1` to `v2` and `v3`  but I could not traverse from `v3` to `v4`

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you get your terminology straight. L1, L2, L3 are *edges* not vertices.

So, you want to hide all *edges* and additionally all vertices with degree 0.

You *could* instead give edges a visibility flag:

```
struct EdgeProps {
    bool _isVisible = true;
};

using BGType = boost::adjacency_list< //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::bidirectionalS,            //
    VertexProps,                      //
    EdgeProps>;
```

Now I'd make that function:

```
void hide_connections(Name name, BGType& graph) {
    auto it = graph.named_vertices.find(name);
    assert(it != graph.named_vertices.end());
    using boost::make_iterator_range;

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(*it, graph)))
        graph[e]._isVisible = false;

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(*it, graph)))
        graph[e]._isVisible = false;
}
```

Now, the visibility of vertices is **a resultant** - a derived property. You could calculate it on the fly:

```
auto visible = [&graph](V v) {
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, graph)))
        if (graph[e]._isVisible)
            return true;
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(v, graph)))
        if (graph[e]._isVisible)
            return true;
    return false;
};
```

Indeed, this satisfies your requirements: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/PrT31Wbqq)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Name = std::string;

struct VertexProps {
    VertexProps(Name n = "unnamed") : name(std::move(n)) {}
    Name name;
};

struct EdgeProps {
    bool _isVisible = true;
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<VertexProps> {
    using type = boost::graph::vertex_from_name<VertexProps>;
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_name<VertexProps> {
    struct type {
        using result_type = Name;
        Name const& operator()(VertexProps const& vp) const { return vp.name; } 
        Name&       operator()(VertexProps& vp) const       { return vp.name; } 
    };
};

using BGType = boost::adjacency_list< //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::bidirectionalS,            //
    VertexProps,                      //
    EdgeProps>;

using V = BGType::vertex_descriptor;
using E = BGType::edge_descriptor;

void hide(Name name, BGType& graph) {
    auto it = graph.named_vertices.find(name);
    assert(it != graph.named_vertices.end());

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(*it, graph)))
        graph[e]._isVisible = false;

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(*it, graph)))
        graph[e]._isVisible = false;
}

int main() {
    BGType graph;

    for (auto [from, to] : {
            std::pair{"V1", "V2"},
            {"V1", "V3"},
            {"V3", "V4"},
        })
    {
        add_edge(from, to, graph);
        add_edge(to, from, graph);
    }

    auto visible = [&graph](V v) { return 0 != degree(v, graph); };

    auto names = get(&VertexProps::name, graph);
    auto print = [&](std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(graph))) {
            if (!visible(v))
                continue;
            os << names[v] << " -->";
            for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, graph))) {
                if (graph[e]._isVisible)
                    os << " " << names[target(e, graph)];
            }
            os << "\n";
        }
    };

    print();

    hide("V1", graph);

    print(std::cout << "\nConnections of V1 hidden:\n");
}
```

Prints

```
V2 --> V1
V1 --> V2 V3
V3 --> V1 V4
V4 --> V3

Connections of V1 hidden:
V3 --> V4
V4 --> V3
```

### Outside The Box

This is clumsy and inefficient:

```
auto visible = [&graph](V v) {
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, graph)))
        if (graph[e]._isVisible)
            return true;
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(v, graph)))
        if (graph[e]._isVisible)
            return true;
    return false;
};
```

What you really want to be able to say is:

```
auto visible = [&graph](V v) { return 0 != degree(v, graph); };
```

However, it won't work *because you don't actually delete anything*, so BGL will think the edges are still there.

You can fix the model by using a `filtered_graph_adaptor` where you store the filterables OUTSIDE the graph model.

### Filtered Graph

So, this shifts the perspective back to your original: *hiding vertices*. Let's start out simple:

```
std::set<V> vhidden;
std::set<E> ehidden;
```

This is the set that will contain all hidden vertex descriptors.

Now we can setup filter predicates and the adapted graph:

```
std::function epred = [&](E e) { return not ehidden.contains(e); };
std::function vpred = [&](V v) { return not vhidden.contains(v); };

boost::filtered_graph f(graph, epred, vpred);
```

Adding some helpers to hide edges/vertices.

```
auto ehide = [&](E e) {
    if (auto u = target(e, graph); 0 == degree(u, f))
        vhidden.insert(u);
    ehidden.insert(e);
};
```

Notice that we're being lazy and using `degree(v, f)` *on the filtered graph* (!) so that we don't have to manually count the number of edges that were already filtered.

```
auto vhide = [&](Name const& name) {
    auto it = graph.named_vertices.find(name);
    assert(it != graph.named_vertices.end());
    V v = *it;
    vhidden.insert(v);

    for (auto e: make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, graph)))
        ehide(e);
    for (auto e: make_iterator_range(in_edges(v, graph)))
        ehide(e);
};
```

Hiding a vertex traverses exactly one level to neighbours unconditionally. That's good enough as a stopping condition (in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996393/how-to-iterate-over-boost-graph-and-find-neighbors-neighbor-also/71999968?noredirect=1#comment127224026_71999968)) because the degree cannot change unless by hiding more edges to the same target node.

Using the filtered view:

```
std::cout << "Filtered edges(" << ehidden.size() << "), vertices(" << vhidden.size() << ")\n";
print_graph(f, names, std::cout << "Filtered view: \n");

vhide("V1");

std::cout << "Filtered edges(" << ehidden.size() << "), vertices(" << vhidden.size() << ")\n";
print_graph(f, names, std::cout << "Connections of V1 hidden:\n");
```

See it **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/8eM5xznb4)**

```
Filtered edges(0), vertices(0)
Filtered view: 
V2 --> V1 
V1 --> V2 V3 
V3 --> V1 V4 
V4 --> V3 
Filtered edges(4), vertices(2)
Connections of V1 hidden:
V3 --> V4 
V4 --> V3
```

#### Full Listing (Filtered Graph)

For posterity: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/8eM5xznb4)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Name = std::string;

struct VertexProps {
    VertexProps(Name n = "unnamed") : name(std::move(n)) {}
    Name name;
};

struct EdgeProps {
    bool _isVisible = true;
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_constructor<VertexProps> {
    using type = boost::graph::vertex_from_name<VertexProps>;
};

template <> struct boost::graph::internal_vertex_name<VertexProps> {
    struct type {
        using result_type = Name;
        Name const& operator()(VertexProps const& vp) const { return vp.name; } 
        Name&       operator()(VertexProps& vp) const       { return vp.name; } 
    };
};

using BGType = boost::adjacency_list< //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::vecS,                      //
    boost::bidirectionalS,            //
    VertexProps,                      //
    EdgeProps>;

using V = BGType::vertex_descriptor;
using E = BGType::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    BGType graph;

    for (auto [from, to] : {
            std::pair{"V1", "V2"},
            {"V1", "V3"},
            {"V3", "V4"},
        })
    {
        add_edge(from, to, graph);
        add_edge(to, from, graph);
    }

    auto names = get(&VertexProps::name, graph);

    print_graph(graph, names, std::cout << "Unfiltered graph:\n");

    std::set<V> vhidden;
    std::set<E> ehidden;

    std::function epred = [&](E e) { return not ehidden.contains(e); };
    std::function vpred = [&](V v) { return not vhidden.contains(v); };

    boost::filtered_graph f(graph, epred, vpred);

    auto ehide = [&](E e) {
        if (auto u = target(e, graph); 0 == degree(u, f))
            vhidden.insert(u);
        ehidden.insert(e);
    };
    auto vhide = [&](Name const& name) {
        auto it = graph.named_vertices.find(name);
        assert(it != graph.named_vertices.end());
        V v = *it;
        vhidden.insert(v);

        for (auto e: make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, graph)))
            ehide(e);
        for (auto e: make_iterator_range(in_edges(v, graph)))
            ehide(e);
    };

    std::cout << "Filtered edges(" << ehidden.size() << "), vertices(" << vhidden.size() << ")\n";
    print_graph(f, names, std::cout << "Filtered view: \n");

    vhide("V1");

    std::cout << "Filtered edges(" << ehidden.size() << "), vertices(" << vhidden.size() << ")\n";
    print_graph(f, names, std::cout << "Connections of V1 hidden:\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have a doubt. In your `void hide_connections()` if i start with `v1` then I can visit `v2` and `v3`. But I do not want to stop there. If `v2` has any more neighbor that also I need to check. Like `v3` has a neighbor `v4`, so I want to iterate over `v4` also. If `v4` has neighbor then I need to go from `v4` to that neighbor.  How to do that ?

Comment: In my code, I am finding only neighbor but I want to check neighbor's neighbor also. And what is the stopping condition? If I visit a node, and if it can not be hidden ( because it's in-degree or out-degree  > 0 ) then its neighbor I will not check.

Comment: You do want to stop there, because the rest is not modified, unless they were connected in the first place. This is closely related to what I meant with "The visibility of vertices is a resultant" (it follows directly from, and depends solely on, the visibility of edges). Of course, you will continue to be confused if you really need to focus on hidding _vertices_ - which **can** be done, but shifts the perspective.

Comment: I added the filtered-graph approach. It does make things easier (you can just use `print_graph` on it e.g.). Hopefully the explanation helps you along the way.